# Flutter TextFormField TextInputAction.done is not an option with keyboard type numbers

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a form with a Column of TextFormFields.  My issue is that when I give a TextFormField a `keyboardType: TextInputType.number` and `textInputAction: TextInputAction.done` the textInputAction doesn't show up.  This is not an issue for me with other keyboard types...

My question is: How do I create a TextFormField that has a keyboard with only numbers *And* have a textInputAction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your textFormField

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true),
inputFormatters: [
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
],
```

Answer (score 2):

iOS doesn’t support Done on keyboards,
Use

```
TextFormField(
        keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
          signed: true,
        ),
        inputFormatters: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
        ],
      ),
```